# Requests timing out when accesing a Kubernetes clusterIP service

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, kubeadm, flannel, kubernetes-service

I am looking for help to troubleshoot this basic scenario that isn't working OK:

Three nodes installed with **kubeadm** on **VirtualBox VMs** running on a MacBook:

```
sudo kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
kubernetes-master   Ready     master    4h        v1.10.2
kubernetes-node1    Ready     <none>    4h        v1.10.2
kubernetes-node2    Ready     <none>    34m       v1.10.2
```

The Virtualbox VMs have 2 adapters: 1) Host-only 2) NAT. The node IP's from the guest computer are:

```
kubernetes-master (192.168.56.3)
kubernetes-node1  (192.168.56.4)
kubernetes-node2  (192.168.56.5)
```

I am using flannel pod network (I also tried Calico previously with the same result).

When installing the master node I used this command:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.3
```

I deployed an nginx application whose pods are up, one pod per node:

```
nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-sk5zs   1/1       Running   0          14m       10.244.2.2   kubernetes-node2
nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-sqjgb   1/1       Running   0          14m       10.244.1.2   kubernetes-node1
```

I exposed them as a ClusterIP service:

```
sudo kubectl get services 
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   22m
nginx-deployment   ClusterIP   10.98.206.211   <none>        80/TCP    14m
```

Now the problem:

I ssh into kubernetes-node1 and curl the service using the cluster IP:

```
ssh 192.168.56.4
---
curl 10.98.206.211
```

Sometimes the request goes fine, returning the nginx welcome page. I can see in the logs that this requests are always answered by the pod in the same node (kubernetes-node1). Some other requests are stuck until they time out. I guess that this ones were sent to the pod in the other node (kubernetes-node2).

The same happens the other way around, when ssh'd into kubernetes-node2 the pod from this node logs the successful requests and the others time out.

I seems there is some kind of networking problem and nodes can't access pods from the other nodes. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I downscaled the number of replicas to 1, so now there is only one pod on kubernetes-node2

If I ssh into kubernetes-node2 all curls go fine. When in kubernetes-node1 all requests time out.

**UPDATE 2:**

**kubernetes-master ifconfig**

```
cni0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::20a0:c7ff:fe6f:8271  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:58:0a:f4:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10478  bytes 2415081 (2.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11523  bytes 2630866 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:cd:ce:84:a9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe2d:298f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:2d:29:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20784  bytes 2149991 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26567  bytes 26397855 (26.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:f08a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:09:f0:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12662  bytes 12491693 (12.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4507  bytes 297572 (297.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::c078:65ff:feb9:e4ed  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c2:78:65:b9:e4:ed  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 444 (444.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 444 (444.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 15 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 464615  bytes 130013389 (130.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 464615  bytes 130013389 (130.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tunl0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1440
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethb1098eb3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::d8a3:a2ff:fedf:4d1d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether da:a3:a2:df:4d:1d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10478  bytes 2561773 (2.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11538  bytes 2631964 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**kubernetes-node1 ifconfig**

```
cni0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::5cab:32ff:fe04:5b89  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:58:0a:f4:01:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 199  bytes 41004 (41.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 331  bytes 56438 (56.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:0f:02:bb:ff  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe36:741a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:36:74:1a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12834  bytes 9685221 (9.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9114  bytes 1014758 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb2:23a3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b2:23:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13263  bytes 12557808 (12.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5065  bytes 341321 (341.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.1.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::7815:efff:fed6:1423  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:15:ef:d6:14:23  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 483  bytes 37506 (37.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 483  bytes 37506 (37.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 15 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3072  bytes 269588 (269.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3072  bytes 269588 (269.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth153293ec: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::70b6:beff:fe94:9942  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:b6:be:94:99:42  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 81  bytes 19066 (19.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 129  bytes 10066 (10.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**kubernetes-node2 ifconfig**

```
cni0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.244.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::4428:f5ff:fe8b:a76b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:58:0a:f4:02:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 184  bytes 36782 (36.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 284  bytes 36940 (36.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:7f:e9:79:cd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb7:ff54  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b7:ff:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12634  bytes 9466460 (9.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8961  bytes 979807 (979.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed8:9210  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:d8:92:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12658  bytes 12491919 (12.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4544  bytes 297215 (297.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.244.2.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::c832:e4ff:fe3e:f616  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:32:e4:3e:f6:16  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 111  bytes 8466 (8.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 111  bytes 8466 (8.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 15 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2940  bytes 258968 (258.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2940  bytes 258968 (258.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**UPDATE 3:**

**Kubelet logs:**

[kubernetes-master kubelet logs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-master-kubelet-log)

[kubernetes-node1 kubelet logs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-node1-kubelet-log)

[kubernetes-node2 kubelet logs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-node2-kubelet-log)

**IP Routes**

**Master**

```
kubernetes-master:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.15 
10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.0.1 
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.3
```

**Node1**

```
kubernetes-node1:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.15 
10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.1.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.1.1 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.4
```

**Node2**

```
kubernetes-node2:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.15 
10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.3.15 metric 100 
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.5
```

**iptables-save:**

[kubernetes-master iptables-save](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-master-iptables-save)

[kubernetes-node1 iptables-save](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-node1-iptables-save)

[kubernetes-node2 iptables-save](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codependent/kubernetes-cluster-logs/master/kubernetes-node2-iptables-save)

Comment: Take look at [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/), It may help.

Comment: Can you please add ip route to the description ?

Comment: Also, please add kubelet logs.

Comment: Hi there, I just added more info

Comment: Can you please share the output of `iptables-save` from all the nodes?

Comment: Added the iptables-save per node.

Comment: @codependent Did you also checked flags `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables`? They should be equal 1. That looks like an issue with forwarding between nodes.

Comment: I have set those flags to 1 in all nodes and it didn't work either.

Comment: That is definitely the problem with network. May you also try to connect to Nginx using the pod IP address from the different node? It will be like `10.244.1.4:80` or `10.244.2.3:80`.

Comment: I tried, if the IP of the endpoint is for a pod on the same node it's ok, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution this in the end?

Comment: Yes, I tried every pod network until I found one that worked. It was either Romana or Weavenet, I don’t remember which one right now.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a similar problem with my K8s cluster with Flannel.  I had set up the vms with a NAT nic for internet connectivity and a Host-Only nic for node to node communication.  Flannel was choosing the NAT nic by default for node to node communication which obviously won't work in this scenario.

I modified the flannel manifest before deploying to set the ***--iface=enp0s8*** 
argument to the Host-Only nic that should have been chosen (***enp0s8*** in my case).  In your case it looks like ***enp0s3*** would be the correct NIC.  Node to node communication worked fine after that.

I failed to note that I also modified the ***kube-proxy*** manifest to include the ***--cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16*** and ***--proxy-mode=iptables*** which appears to be required as well.

Comment: Can you share with us **flannel** and **kube-proxy** manifests? So we can see how they look like after introducing changes that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Flushed all firewalls with `iptables --flush` and `iptables -tnat --flush` then restart docker fixed it

[check this github issue link](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6139#issuecomment-251558161)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs and the fact that you had problems only with connections between nodes which use Flannel, I guess you had a problem with Flannel CNI during the installation.

In logs from `node1` and `master`, I see the following messages:

```
Error adding network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
Error while adding to cni network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory
```

The root cause can be in network problem between VMs.

I recommend you to create 2 networks for each instance in your cluster - one with NAT for access to the Internet and one Host-only for in-cluster communication.

As an alternative way - you can use `Bridge` mode for interfaces of VMs if your network allows it.

Finally, the only suggestion I can provide - remove all cluster components and initialize cluster one more time using the configuration I mentioned above. That is the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue after raw install kubernetes on raspberrypi cluster, with flannel.

The resolution was to disable ufw firewall.